# How can I show Products tags on same product page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

I'm using WooCommerce plugin.

I want to show "Products tags" for the same product on single product page. I have tried everything and it hasn't worked.

Please, can anyone help me with some solution?

Comment: For your additional thoughts, could you be more explicit. It will be better to open a new question, adding the code you have used, providing a link to your web site and taking your time explaining in details, what is working, what is not and what are your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can use this code snippet to display product tags on single product page template (*`content-single-product.php`*):

```
global $products;
$product_id = $product->id;
$product_tags = get_the_term_list($product_id, 'product_tag', '', ',' );
echo '<p class="single-product-tags">'. __( "Tags: ", "your_theme_slug" ) . $product_tags . '<p>';
```

WC templates reference: [**Overriding Templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

2) You can also use `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook with a priority up to 70, to display your product related tags. You will need to paste this code snippet in the `function.php` file of your active child theme or theme:

```
function display_single_product_tags_after_summary() { 
    global $products;
    $product_id = $product->id;
    $product_tags = get_the_term_list($product_id, 'product_tag', '', ',' );
    echo '<p class="single-product-tags">'. __( "Tags: ", "your_theme_slug" ) . $product_tags . '<p>';
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_single_product_tags_after_summary', 100, 0 );
```

For info > The `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook display order (priorities):

```
/**
 * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
 */
```

References *(and thanks)*:

[Woocommerce, get current product id or title within sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385920/woocommerce-get-current-product-id-or-title-within-sidebar/27394146#27394146)

[Get WooCommerce products tags for array of products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478603/get-woocommerce-products-tags-for-array-of-products/31490375#31490375)

Comment: One more thing ..

1. if i want to remove Links from tags 
2. I want to show tags list wise

Where I need to make changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Well its depends on your theme but standard way is :

```
global $product; // gets the Product object (correspoding to the single page)
$product->get_tags( $product ); // returns an array with product tags
```

Comment: A better answer would be more complete.  OP indicated `single product page`, so you can direct them on: (1) how to copy WooCommerce templates to use the override system, and (2) where / how in the template to add this code, and (3) how to output the tags.